# #cccccc \9 - что это?

Tags: css

Доброго всем.
встретил недавно в когде CSS
вот такую строку:

```
background-color: #cccccc \9;
```

Вроде всё понятно, а что такое "\9" не понятно.
Что это? И для чего этот параметр?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just [google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property) first!

---

`\9` is a "CSS hack" specific to Internet Explorer 7, 8 & 9.

This simply means that the one specific line of CSS ending with a `\9` in place of the `;` is only valid in IE 7, 8 & 9.

Comment: Полагаю ответ нужно принять!)

Comment: Хм, был же просто комментарием сперва. Okay...

Comment: Прочитал, там был пример:

    <div style="width:300px; width:600px \9; background-color:#9C6;">
    test
    </div>

Теперь всё стало ЯСНО! Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: Это хак только для IE8 вроде ) Для остальных осликов свои.

Comment: Не знаю точно для каких именно, но код в комментарии у меня на 9-ом IE сработал.
Получается под IE можно совершенно другой дизайн сайта заделать! Хм... это надо попробовать! В опере див красный, в IE зелёный например + все картинки через css пустить... А если заюзать дисплей блок, дак это вообще 2 СОВЕРШЕННО РАЗНЫХ сайта получиться? Ведь так?

Comment: Единственный дизайн, который отдельно для IE сделать нужно - это большой такой баннер с надписью "Срочно смените браузер".

Делать различную верстку для браузеров исключительно через хаки? Мсье знает толк в извращениях! Если вам это действительно нужно - определение браузера через JS и навешивание соответствующего класса на `<html>`. Или через conditional comments, если только для IЕ.

Интересный такой комментарий. Все стараются сделать дизайн одинаковым, даже для IE - а тут совершенно наоборот. Да вы верстайте как верстается, по стандартам - в IE дизайн все равно отличаться будет :D